# Android Progress Bar showing a certain percentage

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use the android progress bar to show things like stamina out of 100%?

I have had a look at the documentation but it says to use as a loading phase item, I cannot find where you could give the progress bar a number out off 100 to display for that...

Is it possible?

Thanks
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thank you for all that looked at this, seems i didn't read properly, here is the solution..

```
public void ManageStamina()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < 100){
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            mProgress.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

}
```